# Common module execute before code inside route?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I have made  a common module in nodejs , and I am using that common module in route where I want to send notification to all users now the problem is when I call the route 1st the common module is executed then code inside route is executed, but what I want is 1st route code should execute then common module should exec.

**this is the route and noti is the common module**

```
router.post('/',  session, noti, async (req, res) => {
const dt = dateTime.create();
const formatted1 = dt.format('Y-m-d H:M:S');
try {
    const str = req.body.providerId;
    const data = str.split("|");
    const id = data[0];
    const name = data[1];
    const date = req.body.resultDate;
    const digit = req.body.winningDigit;
    const exist = await ABgameResult.findOne({ providerId: id,resultDate:  date,session: req.body.session });
    if (!exist) {
        const details = new ABgameResult({
            providerId: id,
            providerName: name,
            resultDate: date,
            winningDigit: digit,
            status: 0
        });
        const savedGames = await details.save();
        const update1 = await ABgamesProvider.updateOne(
            {_id : id },
            { $set: { providerResult: digit, modifiedAt: formatted1,resultStatus : 1 } }); 
            //resultStatus : 1 i.e; result is declared

        const Resultid = savedGames._id;
        const listData = {
            providerId : id,
            resultDate : date,
            status: 0,
            winningDigit: digit,
            resultId: Resultid,
            providerName: name
        }

        return res.json({
            status : 1,
            message : "Success",
            data: listData
        });
    }
    else {
        const data = 'Details Already Filled For : '+ name +', Session : ' + req.body.session + ', Date: ' + req.body.resultDate;
        res.json(data);
    }
}catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.json(e);
  }
});
```

> now what I want is when else part in the route is executed noti module should not be executed I only want to execute it in if part of the code

**this is the module of noti**

```
module.exports = async function ( req, res,next) {
try
{
    const token = await user.find({ banned : 1, andarBaharNotification: true }, {firebaseId : 1});
        let userToken = [];
        for(index in token){
            userToken.push(token[index].firebaseId);
        }

        const digit = req.body.winningDigit;
        const str = req.body.providerId;
        const data = str.split("|");
        const name = data[1];
        var message = new gcm.Message({
                priority: 'high',             
                data: {
                    title: " ("+name+")",
                    icon: "ic_launcher",
                    body: digit
                }
            });
            sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: userToken }, function (err, response) {
                if (err) console.error('error => ' ,err);
                else console.log('response=> ',response);
            });
        next()
    }
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(400).json({
        status: 0,
        message: 'Something Happpend',
        error: e
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: First of all where is your closing parenthesis of router.post?

Comment: at the end of the route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do this!

```
const noti = require('./noti'); // importing noti
router.post('/',  session, async (req, res) => {
   // DO YOUR STUFF
   noti(req, res);
});
```

Remove `next()` from noti module.

Comment: and i have one more question , is this is the correct way of writing code in nodejs?

Comment: It is one of many ways. In this specific case, I don't see any problem with the code.